# Get Realtime Updates from a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am working on a web app that use Facebook login. The purpose of the app is to get information about fan pages that the user has in his account (for which he got admin privileges). I work mostly with the insights informations but this is not the issue. Now I would like to receive realtime update from the page like new messages, page posts reply etc. I've read the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#realtime
and I don't understand the part about adding the app to the page. It is required that the app to be installed for example in one of the tabs? If so, is there a way not to do that and still receive the informations that I want? Also when I try to create a Realtime Update Subscriptions for the page object no "posts" field was available, then how to get realtime updates about it? I am a little confuse and any guidance and advise is more than welcomed.

P.S. I am using PHP SDK, if this helps with something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've read the documentation

How about reading it *again*?

> I don't understand the part about adding the app to the page. It is required that the app to be installed for example in one of the tabs? If so, is there a way not to do that and still receive the informations that I want?

Quote from the docs part you linked to yourself:

> *Note: You might think that because you're adding this via the tabs API that this is a tab app. It's not. This app isn't visible to users as a page app and isn't managed via any UI.*

---

> Also when I try to create a Realtime Update Subscriptions for the page object no "posts" field was available, then how to get realtime updates about it?

You can subscribe to the page’s *feed*.

Comment: @DanielacostinaVaduva are you getting real time page/feed notifications? The docs is very weak. I have already the app on my page's tab. On the App Real Time configurations it's already set "object: page" and "fields: feed".

Comment: I have all configurated but no notifications in real time :( someone can hrlp us?